# Move rows to another table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want move rows from one table to another (in order  to move unused data to historic storage).

How to do this in most clever way?

I found such solutions but looks like it is not working for Oracle dialect

```
    INSERT dbo.CustomersInactive (
      CustomerID,
      FirstName,
      LastName
) SELECT 
            CustomerID,
            FirstName,
            Lastname
      FROM    (
           DELETE dbo.CustomersActive
           OUTPUT
                   DELETED.CustomerID,
```

Comment: Is your table that huge that it's necessary to move its data to another table? I would usually just use a flag `is_active` or the like instead.

Comment: currently it is not so huge but it will increase over time, so there is a need to schedule a job to periodically archive items.

Comment: Personally, I'd partition the table; that way, it's easy to drop/exchange the partition periodically. (That's assuming that you have an easy way of partitioning the table, such as status flag and possibly date the row got marked inactive)

Comment: Okay, so if it becomes really huge (say many billions of rows) you might want to do something about this. I still think that a flag would suffice, maybe with partitioning the table accordingly. However, if you want the two-tables approach, then I'd write a stored procedure reading from one table, inserting into the other and then deleting from the first.

Comment: if you can run multiple statements in that place, why not merge the CustomersActive and CustomersInactive tables with new data from CustomersActive and the delete from CustomersActive. I can write you an example later if you find this solution possible as I have no access to sqlplus right now to test it

Comment: I do really appreciate all your responses. Partition is viable option, however in this topic I'd like to focus how to achieve this using SQL or PL/SQL. @przemo_pl please share your proposed solution.

Answer (score 1):

This solution seems working:

```
DECLARE
   TYPE CustomerSet IS TABLE OF CustomersActive%ROWTYPE;
   inactive CustomerSet;
BEGIN

delete from CustomersActive returning  CustomerID,FirstName,Lastname bulk collect into inactive;

FOR i IN inactive.FIRST .. inactive.LAST LOOP  
        insert into CustomersInactive values (inactive(i).CustomerID,inactive(i).FirstName,inactive(i).Lastname);
END LOOP;        

END;
```

Comment: it will work but still, you will kill it with pl/sql. Even if you're using bulk collect, it will be much slower than SQL

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is the case you need:

```
--init objects
create table active_cust
(cust_id integer,
 name varchar2(100 char)
 );

create table inactive_cust as 
select * 
  from active_cust 
 where 1=2;

--init data
insert into active_cust values (1, 'Przemo');
insert into active_cust values (2,'Pan Miecio');
insert into active_cust values (3,'Pan Franio');

insert into inactive_cust values (3,'Pan Franio');

--merge active and inactive
merge into inactive_cust dest
using (select * from active_cust) srce
on (srce.cust_id = dest.cust_id)
when not matched then insert values
  (srce.cust_id, srce.name )
  --here specify conditions on which customer is being
  --accounted as inactive
  /*where srce.some_status_date < sysdate - 100 */
  ;--only two rows merged as we have >Pan Franio< already in a list of inactive customers!

--now as we have all inactive customers in inactive_cust table, delete from active_cust where id is present in inactive_cust
delete from active_cust ac
 where ac.cust_id in (select cust_id
                            from inactive_cust);

drop table active_cust;
drop table inactive_cust;
```